# Auth0: /userinfo returning unauthorized even if JWT access token is not expired

Tags: jwt, auth0

I have a javascript SPA application that uses Auth0 for authorization and authentication. Users can use social accounts (Google or Facebook). My goal is to keep the users logged in for a rather long time (e.g. 10 days).

I increased the JWT expiration date to 10 days (864000 seconds).

When the user logs in, I store the access token and id token in cookies (who also have an expire time of 10 days). When the page is loaded, the application checks the expire date on the access token. If it is expired, it performs a new login. Otherwise, it assumes it is still logged in.

After this procedure, the application sends a request to the /userinfo endpoint. This works fine for some time (a few hours), but after that, the /userinfo endpoint returns 401 (unauthorized), even though the token has not yet expired.

Using checkSession also fails.

What am I missing?

Comment: As per OpenID Connect spec, the userinfo endpoint requires access tokens with at least scope `openid`. Is it correctly set?

Comment: Yes, the scope is set to `openid profile email`. Apart from the scope, I'm also setting a responseType, redirectUri and audience:
`webAuth.authorize({
  responseType: 'token id_token',
  redirectUri: REDIRECT,
  audience: AUDIENCE,
  scope: 'openid profile email'
});`